# How do I access an ice:dataTable's varStatus, an ice:dataPaginator's firstRowIndexVar? Where are they?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

How can I access the varStatus variable and the firstRowIndexVar variable programmatically? I couldn't find them in the request parameters. I'd even be happy just to inspect them in the debugger.

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 0):

They are not part of the request parameters. They are part of the JSF component tree in the server side. Start with [`FacesContext#getViewRoot()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29). To ease debugging, consider binding the component to a backing bean using `binding` attribute. E.g.

```
<ice:dataTable binding="#{bean.dataTable}">
```

with

```
public class Bean {
    private UIData dataTable;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried the binding, but couldn't find the varStatus variable in there. I did see the varStatus="varStatus" property, but I want to see the varStatus's subproperties.

Comment: I tried the binding, but couldn't find the varStatus variable in the dataTable or outside of it. I did see the varStatus="varStatus" property, but what I want to see is varStatus's subproperties, like begin, end, index, first, last. ICE states that varStatus is the "Name of a request-scope attribute under which the current indexed state will be exposed." So I looked in the request. I also tried the control-shift-d component tree. Nada... What am I doing wrong? Thanks, Eli

Comment: Oh, it's a request attribute? You should then look in request attributes, not in request parameters. From the FacesContext on, they are available by ExternalContext#getRequestMap().